# Is the law of large numbers reflected in SO reputation system?

Tags: number-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I have recently encountered an interesting phenomenon on SO reputation system:

Let $f(n)$ denote the current score of the $n$th best user.

A sample that I collected at a given moment:

- $f(k)=k \implies k\approx7920$
- $f(k)=2k \implies k\approx5470$
- $f(k)=4k \implies k\approx3740$
- $f(k)=8k \implies k\approx2545$
- $f(k)=16k \implies k\approx1695$
- $f(k)=32k \implies k\approx1115$

**The ratio appears approximately $1.5$ in all cases.**

Now, obviously, the SO reputation system wasn't design to yield a relative scoring system amongst users, but an absolute one, based on some arbitrary table of "score per event".

Nevertheless, in the overall perspective given above, this scoring system appears to be giving a very tight relation between the scores of different users.

Of course, I should probably conduct the measurements above over a period of time, but it feels as if there's a "guiding hand" behind this.

I doubt it is made intentionally by "SO managers", so my question is, could it be the reflection of the [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) within a [wisdom of the crowd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom_of_the_crowd) based system?

Comment: What ratio? ${}$

Comment: @whacka: $\frac{7920}{5470},\frac{5470}{3740}$, etc (wasn't quite sure how to express this in mathematical notation).

Comment: I propose this to show ratio maybe, $\frac{f_{i}}{f_{i +1}}$ where the index maps to the group boundary. It seems you are looking for self similarity I.e scaling also.

Comment: @Chinny84: Can you add `/displaystyle` to that fraction (or change it from `/frac` to `/dfrac`)?

Comment: To be honest it's a throw away comment. If it was an answer for sure I would change it. Cheers for the advice mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This scaling is usually referred to as a [power law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law). To see why, note that one assumes that for every nonnegative integer $i$, $k=a/r^i$ solves the equation $f(k)=2^ik$, for some fixed $a\gt0$ and $r\gt1$, that is, $f(a/r^i)=a2^i/r^i$ for every $i$.

If $x=a/r^i$ then $i=\log(a/x)/\log r$ and $a2^i/r^i=x2^i=x\mathrm e^{i\log2}=x(a/x)^{\log2/\log r}$, hence the functional equation translates as $$f(x)=bx^c,$$ with $b=a^{\log2/\log r}$ and $c=1-(\log2/\log r)$. 
Since $r\gt1$, $c$ can take every value $c\lt1$. If $r=1.5$ then $c=-0.709511$.

Comment: The law of large numbers seems squarely off topic.